# Regarding Simplification of Variance Expression

Tags: regression, covariance, variance

I need a simple clarification on how one line turns into the next, and what the general rule is. Help would be much appreciated. This is in relation to a proof for an expression of sum of squared errors of prediction (SSE).

$$ \sum_i \mathrm{Var}[Y_i - \overline Y - b_1(X_i - \overline X)]$$

$$ \sum_i [\mathrm{Var}(Y_i - \overline Y) - 2\mathrm{Cov}(Y_i - \overline Y, b_1(X_i - \overline X)) + (X_i - \overline X)^2\mathrm{Var}(b_1)]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint 1*:

$$ \mathbb{V}[X+Y] = \mathbb{V}[X] + \mathbb{V}[Y] + 2\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)  $$

if $X$ and $Y$ are two correlated random variables.

*Hint 2*:

$$ \mathbb{V}[a X] = a^2 \mathbb{V}[X] $$

if $a$ is a constant.

remains for you to find to what $X$ and $Y$ here correspond in your case (last hint, it's not $X_i$ and $Y_i$).

Comment: Got it, I realized I'd done a complete flop and disregarded the formula. As a general rule of thumb with these cases, is it best to separate `X's` and `Y's`?